# Upgrade Debian from 7.3 to 7.5 (NOT to 7.9 or 8)

Tags: debian, upgrade

I have several machines with Debian 7.5 and one with 7.3.

I want to upgrade the 7.3 machine to 7.5 in order to have all my machines with the same Debian version. After some time I am going to do a full upgrade to `jessie`, but somewhere in the future.

That is my question: how to upgrade from 7.3 to 7.5 and NOT to 7.8, 7.9 or 8? When I use `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` with the `--simulate` option it tells me that all packages are going to be upgraded to version 7.9, which I do not want to happen.

Here are my lines in `sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.bg.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
deb http://ftp.bg.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib
```

Okay, I have the word `wheezy` here (not `stable`, because this will upgrade to `jessie`), but how to point out the version in `sources.list`? Is there any way I can overwrite these lines with links to repository for 7.3?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want the latest the 7.x branch has to offer? IMO, security updates should be installed anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `snapshot.debian.org` service. Point your apt/sources.list to a specific date:

(In your case, the release date for 7.5 (27042014) or  7.6 - 1day (11072014), I suppose.)

From http://snapshot.debian.org/ :

```
If you want to add a specific date's archive to your
apt sources.list simply add an entry like these:

deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20091004T111800Z/ lenny main
```

Adapted example for you:

```
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140710T222555Z/ wheezy main
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a Debian 7.5 machine that hasn't run `apt-get update` or similar since it was upgraded to 7.5 **AND** still has the downloaded packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives` then you could:

On 7.3 machine:

1. `rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
2. `apt-get clean`

On 7.5 machine:

1. `scp -p /var/lib/apt/lists/* 7.3-machine:/var/lib/apt/lists`
2. `scp -p /var/cache/apt/archives/* 7.3-machine:/var/cache/apt/archives/`

Back on 7.3 machine:

1. `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

DO NOT RUN `apt-get update` first, as that will overwrite the lists files you copied from the 7.5 machine.

Comment: Thank you. This is a clever way to do the upgrade to 7.5 and it would work, but the problem is that on all 7.5 machines `apt-get update` was already run many times... And in `archives` they have the latest versions of packages... But thank you for your answer. In other situation I will know how to do it.

Comment: The only other thing i can think of is to download the CD or DVD images for 7.5 with `jigdo` from http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/, and setting up one of your machines as a repository to serve the 7.5 packages.  Then configure the 7.3 machine's sources.list to use that and upgrade it.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I will try and post results. Thanks again!

Comment: It's a LOT of work for just one machine....would be much easier to upgrade them all to 7.9.  Keep us posted on how it turns out.